# Use of Minimum and Count in sql

Tags: sql

Can you use min(count()) to find the smallest number of entries

or is there a way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to do actually ?

Comment: Did you give it a try ?

Comment: the question asks to find the minimum number of recorded recreations for a person in a table

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern,

```
SELECT  MIN(cnt) 
FROM
(
    SELECT  COUNT(colName) cnt
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY ...
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by, and then order by and select top 1, these are all very very standard SQL commands not being rude, but http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp has some very good tutorials, good luck

Answer (score 0):

In `ORACLE` we can use nested aggregate functions like `MIN(COUNT(*))` and `MAX(COUNT(*))` 
but the thing is there should not be any other attribute in the select along with it  or else it will through 
error like

`ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

and in the same way there should be a `GROUP BY` clause associated with it else
it will throw error

`ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY`

To just know the minimum record recreations your query will be

```
 select min(count(rec_recreation)) as cnt from table group by person;
```

If you want something like which person has minimum record recreations then

```
select person,cnt from (select person,count(rec_recreation) cnt from table group by person)
where cnt = (select min(count(rec_recreation)) from table group by person)
```